# Variables in templates.cfg in Telosys

Tags: telosys

There are some variables in templates.cfg that could be used, like ${SRC} , ${ROOT_PKG} , ${BEANNAME} , ...

I would like to know the list of variables that could be used, and also it if it possible to get the database information configured in databases.dbcfg . For example, I want to use the database name and schema in the path of the generated files.

I would like to execute a template like

```
JPA record (without links)  ; ${BEANNAME}.java      ; ${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}/model/${database.name} ; XxxJpaRecord_java.vm ; *
```

but it creates a folder with the name "${database.name}" instead creating a folder with the name of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Each Telosys project has a set of variables : "standard variables" and “specific project variables”. These variables are usable in every template of the current project (whatever the templates bundle).

All the project variables are defined in the "**telosys.cfg**" file. This file is a text file editable with any text editor (you can also use the "ecfg" command if you are using Telosys-CLI).
In this file you can set the "standard variables" (like SRC, RES, etc) and your own "project variables" (specific variables with "**ProjectVariable.**" prefix) all variables are usable in the templates and in the "templates.cfg" files). By convention the variables names are in capitals.

In your example you just have to define a new "project variable" in the "**telosys.cfg**" file, for example:

```
ProjectVariable.DATABASE_NAME=mydb
```

and use it in your "**templates.cfg**" files

```
${SRC}/${ROOT_PKG}/model/${DATABASE_NAME}
```

Comment: What about c# asp.net core solution with multiple projects: MVC razor pages, Application, Infrastructure, Common. What are these standard variables referring to?